# How can I fix the 'InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am getting the above mentioned error message while retrieving data from my mysql db.

The method workes properly with other tables such as 'users' however, I am not seeing the problem why it's not working with the client table as well.

**Client Entity:**

```
public class Client : IEntity<int>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Entities Entity { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ClientBusinessSector> Client_Business_Sectors{ get; set; }
            = new List<ClientBusinessSector>();

        [ForeignKey("Country_Id")]
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        public int Country_Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("City_Id")]
        public City City { get; set; }
        public int City_Id { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ClientUser> Client_Users { get; set; }
            = new List<ClientUser>();

        public ICollection<ClientService> Client_Services { get; set; }
            = new List<ClientService>();

        public enum Entities
        {
            GmbH = 1,
            AG,
            Einzelfirma,
            Kollektivgesellschaft,
            Genossenschaft
        }
    }
```

**Controller-Level:**

```
[HttpGet()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllClients()
    {
        var clientsFromRepo = await _clientRepository.GetAllAsync();
        var clients = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientDto>>(clientsFromRepo);

        return Ok(clients);
    }
```

Repository Methods that are being called from the controller:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Set<TEntity>()
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

I need to get a List of clients from my db. Even if it would be an empty list it should return a 200 Ok Status. The repository methods are working properly with other tables but for some reason not with the client table

The error message I get: *InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.*

Answer (score 1):

I just found the bug:
I had in my DbContext a modelbuilder.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .Property(c => c.Entity)
            .HasConversion<string>();
    }
```

Took it out and it's working properly as it should :)